# Trouble with memcpy in release mode

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008

I have a piece of code which works well in debug mode in visual studio but crashes in release mode. After a lot of guess work, i found the piece of code which is causing the crash.

```
char *buff ="some random text";
char *temp = NULL;
char *pos = NULL;
int len = strlen("random text");

pos = strstr(buff,"random");
temp = (char *) malloc(len+1);
memset(temp,0,len+1);
memcpy(temp,pos,len);
```

This works perfectly in debug mode, but crashes in release. Could any one point out the error ?

Comment: I checked this piece of code in visual studio 2010 in both Debug mode and Release mode... It works perfectly. I assume that you doubt this piece of code in a large program.. I have to say, this part is not creating the trouble

Comment: have you "free" the pointer allocated

Comment: @hazzelnuttie I fixed the problem, I was doing at a place above this code, strlen(temp+3) instead of strlen(temp)+3 !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code section shown looks fine.As an addition with unwind's answer.Possible reasons of failing may be

1)uninitialised variables

2)the preprocessor symbols _DEBUG and NDEBUG. If you have any code inside an #ifdef _DEBUG / #endif block.

3)compiler optimisation

Comment: did you try after turning off optimization?

Comment: so better you start debugging in release mode.you can debug a release build. Just go to 'Project -> Settings', choose the Win32 Release configuration, tab 'C/C++', 'General' and set 'Debug Info' to 'Program Database'. Then go to the tab 'Linker', and turn on 'Generate Debug Info'. If you rebuild your project now, you will be able to run it in the debugger. Regardless of whether your program crashes or just doesn't behave as expected, running it in the debugger will show you why.

Comment: i found the problem,  I was doing at a place above this code, strlen(temp+3) instead of strlen(temp)+3 !! Thanks for ur help

Answer (score 1):

It looks legit, a few minor nitpicks as usual:

1. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
2. Use more `const`: `buff`, `pos` and `len` should all be declared `const`.
3. Most importantly, check the return value of `malloc()` before accessing the memory.

Comment: tried it, malloc returns memory, so tht isnt the issue either

Answer (score -1):

When you use malloc try

```
temp  = malloc((len + 1) *sizeof(*temp));
```

Comment: This is pointless, `sizeof *temp == sizeof (char) == 1` so scaling by that has no effect.